# Crawler gets the asked code twice

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple html dom parser and everything works fine, but my code produces the asked code multiple times.
U can see what I'm talking about here:
http://stijnaerts.be/crawl/

I'm using the following php code:

```
<?php
                include("simple_html_dom.php");

                $webpage ="http://www.partyindustries.be/partypics/";

                $html = file_get_html($webpage);

                $links = $html->find('a');

                foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
                    $div = $element->find('div[.kalenderRow partyPicsRow]');
                    $som = count($div);
                    if($som != 0)
                    {
                        echo $element;
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

What is causing the multiple entries?

Comment: where is multiple entries ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `div[.kalenderRow .partyPicsRow]`?

Comment: @putvande No, it should work as it is

Comment: Are you allowed to take the pictures/albums (copyright, property of) ?

Comment: if u follow the images on the right side on the website, u can see the same images after a while
@ danfromgermany: i'm just going to link to the albums, generating more traffic for the websites.

Comment: I do not know the library you are using, but for this job you are trying to, I would use the Goute : https://github.com/fabpot/goutte

Comment: does noone have a solution?

Comment: It's being caused by a bug in simple_html_dom. You should consider switching to a different library.